# Stop rails from including type in belongs_to with Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sti

I have a problem where rails is adding unnecessary (I think) clauses to my belongs_to association - restricting on type even though my association is using a foreign key.

The STI setup looks like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :apple
end

class Apple < Fruit
  has_many :foos
end
```

So `Foo` has an `apple_id` column which links to the primary key column ID in `fruits`, and `Apple` is STI under `Fruit`. I'm happy with all of this.

Now:

```
> Foo.joins(:apple).to_sql

SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "fruits" ON "fruits"."id" = 
"foos"."apple_id" AND "fruits"."type" IN ('Apple')
```

Why is rails adding `AND "fruits"."type" IN ('Apple')`? It's a belongs_to using a primary key of the `fruits` table, so the type part seems redundant.  Can I stop rails from adding that part to the lookups and just get this:

```
SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "fruits" ON "fruits"."id" = 
"foos"."apple_id"
```

I know I could do `belongs_to :apple, :class_name => "Fruit"` in Foo, but I want the objects to auto-become `Apple`s when they're returned.

In case someone questions my motives... I want to do this because the type clause is messing up the query plan postgres chooses when I'm doing a query through `fruits` to other tables (yes, I have an index on `type` and even tried a multi-column one on `[type,id]`). That's a little complicated / irrelevant to describe fully here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically AM is adding the ('Apple') part because in order to respect the inheritance chain.

For example if you'd have

```
class GreenApple < Apple
end
```

You'll get.

> Foo.joins(:apple).to_sql 
>   SELECT "foos".* FROM "foos" INNER JOIN "fruits" ON "fruits"."id" = "foos"."apple_id" AND "fruits"."type" IN ('Apple', 'GreenApple')

If for whatever reason you end up having on your fruits tabel a fruit with a referenced pk but with a different type you could end up instantiating a different kind of object without knowing it and after that things can go wrong without getting an exception.

Comment: Is it possible to turn off that double-check, if I'm sure I'm not going to end up having an incorrect primary key?

Comment: What you could do is to have a belongs_to :fruit. You get rid of the ('Apple') part because no type filtering is necessary. But you can end up associating bananas to the fruit relation, I guess you could solve this with a validation on the Foo model.
Btw AR always returns a model of the type that is specified in the type attribute when doing STI. (and if the type attribute is nil than an instance of the base class is returned)

Comment: That seems similar to the `belongs_to :apple, :class_name => "Fruit"`  I mentioned in my question, which wasn't auto-instantiating to an apple, I don't think. I'll re-check that.

Comment: Woa, that worked. You can call the association whatever you want (:apple is fine) and :class_name => "Fruit", and still get an `Apple`. Don't know how I missed that. Awesome!